# Minimum value of $f$ occurs at $x\implies f'(x)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous and differentiable function on the interval $[a,\,b]$, and suppose that $f$ attains its minimum at point $c\in(a,\,b)$. Show that $f'(c)=0$.

I think an appropriate theorem to apply here would be the Mean Value Theorem which states if a function is continuous and differentiable on $(a,\,b)$ then we can find a $c\in(a,\,b)$ such that $$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.$$

However $(f(b)-f(a))/(b-a)=0\iff f(a)=f(b)$ which we cannot assume so I am certain this is incorrect. I also haven't used the fact that $f(c)$ is the minimum value of $f$ or in other words $f(x)>f(c)$ for every $x\in[a,\,b]$ such that $x\not=c$. However i'm not really sure how to connect these bits of information. Any hints?

Comment: If $f'(x) \neq 0$ in $(a,b)$ then  $f$ is either a strictly increasing function or strictly decreasing.

Answer (score 6):

No, the $c$ given by the MVT most likely isn't the $c$ that's fixed in the statement of your 
theorem.

Instead, all you need is the definition of the derivative: $$f'(c)=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}{f(c+h)-f(c)\over h}.$$ If you assume $f'(c)<0$, you can show, using the definition of limit, that there is an $h>0$  with $c+h<b$ such that $f(c+h)-f(c)<0$. This contradicts the hypothesis that $x=c$ gives a minimum. Similarly, you can argue that $f'(c)>0$ can't hold (take small negative $h$).

Note you only need that $f'(c)$ exists, here.

Comment: Hi, thanks! Can you quickly explain how you found the $h>0$?

Comment: @user2850514 Assume $\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0^+}{f(c+h)-f(c)\over h}=r<0$. Then there is a $\delta>0$ such that ${f(c+h)-f(c)\over h}<r/2<0$ whenever $0<h<\delta$. Pick $h=\delta/2$ (and even smaller if you must to insure $c+h<b$). Then ${f(c+h)-f(c)\over h} <0$. Since $h$ is positive, $f(c+h)-f(c)<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

Once $f'$ is differentiable, you have that for any fixed $z\in\mathbb{R}$ $$f(c+tz)-f(c)=f'(c)tz+o(t),\ \mbox{small}\ t,\ t\neq 0,$$

thus $$\frac{f(c+tz)-f(c)}{t}=f'(c)z+\frac{o(t)}{t}\, \mbox{small}\ t,\ t\neq 0 .$$

Because $c$ is the minimum, you can conlude that $$0\le f'(c)z+\frac{o(t)}{t},\ \mbox{small}\ t,\ t\neq 0.$$

Now, let $t\to 0$ and vary $z$ to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be a continuous and differentiable function on the interval $[a,\,b]$, and suppose that $f$ attains its minimum at point $c\in(a,\,b)$. Show that $f'(c)=0$.

---

Since $f(c)=m$ is the minimum and $f$ is differentiable on $[a,\,b]$ consider $$\lim_{x\to c^{-}} \dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} = \lim_{x\to c^{-}}\dfrac{f(x)-m}{x-c} \le0 \text{ since numerator +ve and denominator -ve.}$$ $$\lim_{x\to c^{+}} \dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} = \lim_{x\to c^{+}} \dfrac{f(x)-m}{x-c} \ge0 \text{ since numerator and denominator +ve.}$$

Therefore the limit only exists if $f'(c) = 0$.

Comment: Your $c$ is not the same $c$ of the question. In your case, $c$ could be $a$ or $b$.

Comment: @Tomás Thanks for saying. Is there any way I could modify this proof so that it works? Are we able to take $c\in(a, b)$ such that $f(c)=m$ since we have assumed above that $f$ has a minimum which isn't at the boundary points?

Comment: You alread have as hypothesis that $c$ is the minimum point for $f$.

Comment: So in reality the first 4 lines are not really needed?

Comment: Yes, this works. Just the last bit. Better than my argument by contradiction, in fact. (In the last line, you want to say "since both numerator and denominator are nonnegative".)

Comment: In fact, you do not need the first 6 lines.

Comment: Yes indeed! Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Add at the start "since $f(c)=m$ is the minimum of $f$".